# Can I store any custom tables in SharePoint system database?

Tags: database, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

**Can I store any custom tables in SharePoint's own database?**
Is this supported behavior or not?

(I mean *tables* in MS SQL *database*, not SharePoint *lists*.)

If I can, **how well does this play with backup/restore functionality**?
What are possible **caveats**?

For anyone wondering why I'm asking: there's an app which is bound to SharePoint server and *needs to store some purely relational internal information that doesn't make sense apart from that SharePoint instance*. I would like to narrow down data storage to one place but I'm not sure if SharePoint likes its database being used for other purposes.

I'm using SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible? Sure. Should you? Nope.

The SharePoint content/configuration databases are subject to change with any update Microsoft releases, and any changes you make will very likely be destroyed, and if your farm depends on them, be left non-functional.

If you want to store purely relational data in a set of tables, just create another database. There's nothing stopping you from using the same SQL Server instance that houses your SharePoint content and/or configuration databases to store *other* relational databases as well.

Comment: Got it. I thought so but was convinced a database engineer otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: SharePoint itself uses multiple databases like mentioned - Config database, seperate db for site collection, for search etc... So go for a dedicated database for your own purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Not a good idea: [Support for changes to the databases used by Windows Sharepoint Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057/en-us)

> ...
>
> - Making any modification to the database schema
> - Adding tables to any of the databases
>
> ...
>
> If an unsupported database modification is discovered during a support call, the customer must perform one of the following procedures at a minimum:
>
> - Perform a database restoration from the last known good backup that did not include the database modifications
> - Roll back all the database modifications

Answer (score 1):

It is even worse than the above.  It is likely that future upgrades will notice your changes to the content database schema and refuse to upgrade the database period.